# Receive Consumer Record/ Result from either a success or a failure response topic using AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-kafka

We are using AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate to retrieve the response from either the success or failure topic. (The success and failure topics are different). If we receive the success then we immediately need to return back to callback and not wait for the timeout ignoring the error. Could someone please suggest any way to handle this or if there is an alternative to achieve this without using AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

?

See the constructor:

```java
/**
 * Construct an instance using the provided parameter arguments. The releaseStrategy
 * is consulted to determine when a collection is "complete".
 * @param producerFactory the producer factory.
 * @param replyContainer the reply container.
 * @param releaseStrategy the release strategy which is a {@link BiPredicate} which is
 * passed the current list and a boolean to indicate if this is for a normal delivery
 * or a timeout (when {@link #setReturnPartialOnTimeout(boolean)} is true. The
 * predicate may modify the list of records.
 * @since 2.3.5
 */
public AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<K, V> producerFactory,
        GenericMessageListenerContainer<K, Collection<ConsumerRecord<K, R>>> replyContainer,
        BiPredicate<List<ConsumerRecord<K, R>>, Boolean> releaseStrategy)
```

Simply configure your release strategy to do whatever you want e.g.

```
(list, to) -> list.size == 1
```

Comment: Hi Gary,
Thanks for the reply.
In ReplyingKafkaTemplate we have the provision to override the default header key for the Correlation ID header. But in AggregartingReplyingKafkaTemplate that provision is not provided. Also, none of the headers received as part of the consumer record are forwarded back to the caller.
Overriding the methods would require quite a bit of code changes.
Could you please suggest how we can proceed?

Comment: Only supporting the default header name is a bug; please open an issue on GitHub https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues your second issue is not clear; the returned consumer record is synthesized from the results, with the `value()` being the list of actual `ConsumerRecord`s received (which will have the headers).

Comment: Thanks Gary!
Sure I will check the second part from my side.
I have raised a GitHub issue for the default header name bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2344